# Is "Region Free Subgraph" an appropriate term for this type of subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, planar-graphs

I'm defining "Region Free Subgraphs" as follows:

> Let $G_e$ be a planar embedding of a graph $G$. The *Region Free Subgraph* of $G_e$ is the subgraph of $G$ made up of all edges in $G$ that are not a member of a bounded face in $G_e$.

#### $G_e$ (region free subgraph in orange)

[image]

Is there another term for this type of subgraph already in use, or should I keep calling them "Region Free Subgraphs"?

### Update

Unless I get a better answer, will use the term “Bridge Subgraphs” based on the feedback I received from @MathewDaly

Comment: I'd call them the set of cut edges (or bridges, depending on your textbook).

Comment: @MatthewDaly Thanks for the response. I want to be sure I’m using a term that refers to the subgraph made up of edges in that set: should I say “Subgraph defined by the set of cut edges/bridges” to make that clear? That’s a bit wordy. Would it be strange/conflict with some other term if I called  it the “Cut Edge Subgraph” or “Bridge Subgraph”?

Comment: Either of those sound great.  (The technical term would be "induced" rather than "defined".)  The sweet thing about being a mathematician is that you can define terms that are valid within the context of your own writing as long as you state those definitions clearly enough that your readers can find them.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Awesome, thanks. Part of why I’m asking is because I’m working on an paper where I defined some terms, only to later discover there were other pretty well know terms for those same definitions (was calling “weak duals” “inner duals”, for example). I’m new to graph theory, so my corpus of terms to draw from is really limited. I’m including strict definitions of these things regardless, but I’d rather not reinvent the wheel too much/want it to use pre-existing terminology wherever possible.

Comment: That's perfectly understandable.  I'm far from an expert on modern research, so your professors and editors will be far more knowledgeable than I am.  But I'd be disappointed in them if they were upset at correcting esoteric terminology, especially if your logic was sound.